# Updating component data from child of sibling component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm a React newbie and I make my application works by try-error and googling. However I want to get feedback from your guys who have more experience in this. It work but I'm not sure I did it in the right way or "best/good practice".

My main concern is the way I updated vehicleId to update VehicleDetails data. To me it was complicated to chain through all states and props to get another component data updated. I hope there is easier way to do this otherwise this will be ugly to send properties and bubble up to app level to trigger update.

How would you do this in a better way?

Many Thanks :)

```
"use strict";

$(function () {


var App = React.createClass({

    displayName: 'App',
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            itemDetails: [],
            selectedVehicleId: null
        }
    },
    setSelectedVehicleId: function(selectedId){
        this.setState({
            selectedVehicleId: selectedId
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return <div>
            <VehicleList setSelectedVehicleId={this.setSelectedVehicleId}/>
            <VehicleDetail selectedVehicleId={this.state.selectedVehicleId} />
        </div>

    }
});

var VehicleList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: [],
            selectedVehicleId: null
        }
    },
    getListItems: function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://baseurl/webapi/vehicle/get',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.log("error");
            }.bind(this)
        });

    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.getListItems();
    },
    setSelectedVehicle: function(e){

        var selectedVehicleId = $(e.target).attr('data-vehicle-id');
        this.props.setSelectedVehicleId(selectedVehicleId);

    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var rows = this.state.data.map(function (vehicle, i) {
            return <VehicleRow setSelectedVehicle={self.setSelectedVehicle} data={vehicle} key={i}/>
        })
        return <div className="container list-content">{rows}</div>
    }
});

var VehicleRow = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return <div className='row'>

            <div className='col-md-6 car-info-container'>
                <div className='vehicle-name' data-vehicle-id={this.props.data.VehicleId} onClick={this.props.setSelectedVehicle}>{this.props.data.VehicleName}</div>
            </div>

        </div>

    }
});

var VehicleDetail = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            itemDetails: []
        }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.selectedVehicleId != this.props.selectedVehicleId) {
            this.getItemDetails(nextProps.selectedVehicleId);
        }else if (nextProps.selectedVehicleId === this.props.selectedVehicleId && this.state.itemDetails.VehicleId){
            this.hideDetails(this.state.itemDetails);
        }
    },
    getItemDetails: function (vehicleId) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://baseurl/webapi/vehicle/getdetails/'+ vehicleId,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({itemDetails:data});
                self.hideDetails(data);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log("error");
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    hideDetails: function(data){
        $('.list-content').hide();
        $('.details-content').show();
    },
    showDetails: function(){
        $('.list-content').show();
        $('.details-content').hide();
    },
    render: function () {
        return <div className="container details-content">
            <button className="btn btn-default back-button" onClick={this.showDetails}>Back</button>
            <div className="image-container">
                <img className='image' src={this.state.itemDetails.ImageUrl}/>
            </div>
            <div className="row vehicle-details-container">
                <h3>Vehicle Details</h3>

                <div className="col-md-6 no-padding">
                    <label className="col-md-3">Location:</label>
                    <span className="col-md-3">{this.state.itemDetails.Location}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 no-padding">
                    <label className="col-md-3">Make:</label>
                    <span className="col-md-3">{this.state.itemDetails.Make}</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    }
});

React.render(<App />, document.body);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to read up on **Flux** once you are comfortable with the UI part of React: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html.

Flux brings unidirectional data flow into React. There are simpler implementations of the same concept ([reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs), [backbone](https://gist.github.com/rattrayalex/d5e14e85702c0a6d78c6), etc) you can check out too.

The basic concept is to let components trigger data changes into a global dispatcher that passes the data through the component hierarchy. And since React only update DOM that has changed, this makes a perfect match for React.